# How to move sites from Favorites bar to Favoritesvmenu?

Tags: internet-explorer, bookmarks

Recently, I added many many sites to the favorites bar in Internet Explorer. Now I want to make that more organised and want to move some the favorites menu instead of the favorites bar?

How can I do that? And if you have any ideas in how to organize my long list in the favorites please explain to me.

The Version I use is IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

To move favorites, click a link or folder and then drag it to the new position or folder. You can also move items by clicking the link or folder, clicking Move, and then choosing the folder you want to move it to.

[source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-to-manage-your-favorites-in-Internet-Explorer-9)